# Change email from and display name with a filter action

Tags: filters, wp-mail

I'm attempting to override the "from" display name and email address using the `wp_mail()` function. I am using the `wp_mail_from` filter hook to modify it with my custom function using       `add_filter('wp_mail_from','abcisupport_wp_mail_from')`.

If I hard code the value, it will return the address so it's wired up properly. If I use the argument, it returns the site network defaults. How can I pass in a value to the arguments (here: `$email` and `$name`) to my overriding functions?

```
function abcisupport_wp_mail_from($email) {
  return $email; //returns our default site network email address
  /* return 'michael@site.com'; // returns  michael@site.com as the from address*/
}

function abcisupport_wp_mail_from_name($name) {
  return $name; //returns our default site network display name

}

function send_abc_mail_before_submit(){
    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
    add_filter('wp_mail_from','abcisupport_wp_mail_from');
    add_filter('wp_mail_from_name','abcisupport_wp_mail_from_name');

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $mailbody, $headers);

    remove_filter('wp_mail_from','abcisupport_wp_mail_from');
    remove_filter('wp_mail_from_name','abcisupport_wp_mail_from_name');
}
```

Note: all fields within the `wp_mail()` function are already set; code above has been simplified for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple possibilities.

**Use the [settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to add a form field somewhere in your admin area** where the user can enter the email they want to use.  Retrieve it in your hooked function with [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

This would be the way to go if you're going to use the same from email everywhere.

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'wpse66067_mail_from');
function wpse66067_mail_from($email)
{
    if($e = get_option('wpse66067_option'))
        return $e;

    return $email; // we don't have anything in the option return default.
}
```

**Use an object, and store the from email as a property.** This would be the way to go if you need to change the from email on a per send basis.

```
<?php
class WPSE66067_Emailer
{
    private static $from_email = 'something@email.com';

    public static  function send_mail()
    {
        add_filter('wp_mail_from', array(__CLASS__, 'from_email');

        // change the email
        self::$from_email = 'some_other_email@example.com';

        wp_mail( /* args here */ );

        // you probably don't need to do this.
        remove_filter('wp_mail_from', array(__CLASS__, 'from_email');
    }

    public static function from_email($e)
    {
        if(self::$from_email)
            return self::$from_email;

        return $e;
    }
}
```

**Use a global.** This is (probably) a terrible idea. If you need to use change the email every time, use an object and a property (see above).

```
<?php
$wpse66067_email = 'something@email.com';

function wpse66067_send_mail()
{
    // globalize and change the email
    global $wpse66067_email;
    $wpse66067_email = 'some_other_email@example.com';

    add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'wpse66067_from_email');

    wp_mail( /* args here */ );
}

function wpse66067_from_email($e)
{
    global $wpse66067_email;
    if($wpse66067_email)
        return $wpse66067_email;

    return $e;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. apologies on the delayed response but you've been tremendous. i wish i could +3 for each of the examples you gave.